# Regular expression which except a-z , A-Z ,0-9 and -(dash)

Tags: regex

I need write a regular expression which accept a-z , A-Z,0-9 and -(dash) as a special character .

```
valid inputs : 1 :  mohit-kumar-gulati
               2 :  mohit1-kumar1-gulati 
               3 :  mohit1-kumar1-gulati 
               4 :  234-545-345

Invalid inputs : 1 :  mohit@-kumar-gulati
                 2 :  mohit1-kumar1$-gulati 
                 3 :  @@@%^-kumar1-gulati 
                 4 :  %^-::-''::
                 5 :  *(*mohit
```

Comment: Can you give an example of accepted string?

Comment: `except` or `accept`?

Comment: Does it *have* to include a dash? And must it contain at least one letter? And please confirm 'except'.

Comment: @Bathsheba **at most** translates to regexp's `?`.

Comment: @devnull probably he meant **expect**, not **except**

Comment: @Teejay You're _probably_ correct but I wouldn't _assume_ that it's _accept_ or _expect_.

Comment: @devnull I deduced it from the fact he said that `-` can appear at most one time.

Comment: I'm afraid it's one of these cases where the user asks something which they could have googled but in such an imprecise way it wastes everyone's time. And then doesn't come back with responses to the comments. I recommend question downvoting for ill-posed and closure for insufficient minimum understanding.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I am in full agreement. Why folks even bother to post a question if thy are not ready to clarify the problem and respond to comments.

Comment: Sorry for the delay replay I meant accept, not except .

Comment: Can you clarify whether empty strings are valid input? Also provide some examples of valid and invalid inputs.

Comment: This is one of the easiest regex, if you have searched on SO you would have found the answer.

Comment: @user1194147 Then my answer is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
[A-Za-z]*-?[A-Za-z]*
```

Comment: It will match empty string also.

Comment: @anubhava Actually, OP did not specified it should not.

Comment: OP hasn't specified anything yet that allows you to answer

Answer (score 0):

If it is C# you should use a regex like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[-\w]+$");
```

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: `\w` includes also `_`.